# Como hacer para que el enlance te lleve a a la misma pagina

Tags: php, html

Tengo una barra vertical, la cual tiene varias cosas, pero en una tiene por decir "Productos" y al dar click se despliega y sale "Registrar Producto" Yo quiero que al dar click en "Registrar Producto" salga un formulario en la parte blanca de la pagina que he dejado, es decir, no quiero que al apretar me lleve a otra pagina con el formulario, quiero que se quede en la msima ¿cómo se puede hacer eso?

Comment: ¿Tienes ya el formulario en la página o quieres cargarlo en la página?  Parece que lo que quieres es lo primero (que se podría hacer cargando algo con AJAX), pero no termina de quedar claro y la respuesta va a depender de eso. 
 Además, sería ideal si editases la pregunta para añadir una descripción de lo que hayas investigado o intentado. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y recomendaciones.

Comment: hola Eduardo te hago una pregunta quieres hacer como una navegación que no recargue la pagina como [tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/)

Comment: Lo que estas intentando hacer es emular un SPA. Por lo que quieres que solo sea una pagina pero en ella ver las otras paginas es correcto?. Si asi fuera lo que quieres que hacer es hacer la llamada al servidor de la pagina que quieres la recepciones con ajax y la insertas. escribeme si te entendi bien para poder ayudarte

Comment: No tengo el formulario en la pagina, quiero cargarlo. Es que investigue, pero no encontre ningun ejemplo, le pongo el ejemplo del Facebook, te logueas y te desconecta y en la parte izquierda queda tu imagen y tu nombre, entonces si le das click alli se te abre para poner la contraseña sin recargar la pagina, es decir, no te lleva a ningun lado, te deja alli mismo solo que carga eso en la misma pagina, me entienden? seguire buscando a ver como puedo explicarlo de una mejor forma.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasar parametros en la url de tus links y mostrar u ocultar elementos con PHP (entre otras varias soluciones). Pero como te dicen quizás lo normal sería usar ajax, o JS+CSS.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="?mostrar">Mostrar</a></li>
    <li><a href="?registrar">Registrar</a></li>
</ul>

<div>
<p>Producto 1</p>
<p>Producto 2</p>
</div>

<?php if(isset($_GET["registrar"])):?>
    <form>
        <input name="loquesea" value="">
        <input type="sunbmit">
    </form>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score -1):

entiendo que necesitas es esto...

```
<a href="#deseoIr">Ir a la parte Blanca</a>

<div id="deseoIr">
    <p>Aqui es la parte Blanca</p>
</div>
```

espero te sirva, me cuentas!

Comment: No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar. Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que son inciertas o deficientes en detalles específicos que puedan identificar el problema real. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: Bueno señor....

Comment: Aunque la pregunta no sea consistente y dificil de entender, si se proporciona una respuesta, no siempre es Copy and Paste ;)

Comment: @srJJ la respuesta es de baja calidad (es básicamente código sin ninguna explicación de lo que hace o de cómo soluciona el problema). Además, como la pregunta no está clara, puede que la respuesta que das (hacer un enlace a un marcador en la página) no sea lo que el usuario busca (que parece más relacionado con tener una aplicación de una sola página y cargar datos en una zona común)